# C - Ordena vetor de tamanho indeterminado

Tags: c

Como imprimir x  | fi corretamente?
Caso o usuário informe...
0 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 4
Ele deveria ordena assim...
0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
E imprimir...
X | fi
0 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 4
3 | 2
4 | 1
Ou seja:

0 aparece 1 vez
1 aparece 2 vezes
2 aparece 4 vezes
3 aparece 2 vezes
4 aparece 1 vez

O código com qual comecei...
Qual imprimir a tabela sem problema algum, e utilizando gets para captura a entrada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

int arr[10] = {0};
char num[200] = {'\0'};
size_t i;

printf("Informe um numero: ");
gets(num);

for ( i = 0; i < strlen(num); i++ )
    arr[ num[i] - '0' ]++;

printf("\nEste numero possui:\n\n");

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    if (arr[i])
        printf("%d digitos %d\n", arr[i], i);

return 0;
}
```

Aqui onde começa os defeito, ao tentar ordena de forma linear o tipo tabela (x | fi) para de funcionar e utilizando scanf("%[^\n]s", n)  em vez de gets. Pois quando utilizava o gets com sort, o vetor ordenado de forma linear ficava com um monte de 0 e a tabela correta. Mas quando uso o scanf ou até mesmo fgets o vetor ordenado de forma linear fica correto e a tabela erra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void sort(int *array, int size);

void sort(int *array, int size){
int x, y, value;
for(x = 1; x < size; x++){
    value = array[x];
    for(y = x - 1; y >= 0 && array[y] > value; y--){
        array[y+1] = array[y];
    }
    array[y+1] = value;
}
}
int main (){
const int BFF = 200;
char num[BFF]={'\0'};
int arr[BFF]={0};
int tam, l;
size_t i;
// Inicializa os vetores
memset(arr, 0, BFF * sizeof(int));
memset(num, '{BARRA}0', BFF * sizeof(char));
// Pega os dados
printf("Informe a amostra: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", num);

// Preenche o vetor com elementos válidos
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(num); ++i) {
    if (isdigit(num[i])) {
        // Converte char para int
        arr[tam] = num[i] - '0';
        tam += 1;
    }
 }
sort(arr,tam);
// Exibe algumas informações
printf("\n");
printf("Tamanho: %d \n", tam);
printf("Amostra ordenada: \n");

// Imprime o vetor já ordenado
for(l=0;l<tam;l++)
        printf("%d ",arr[l]);/*
for ( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    arr[ num[i] - '0' ]++;*/

printf("\nX | fi\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    if (arr[i])
        printf("%d | %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Aqui com fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
const int BFF = 200;
char num[BFF]={'\0'};
int arr[BFF]={0};
size_t i = 0;

printf("Informe a amostra: ");
fgets(num, BFF, stdin);
printf("\n Amostra ordenada:\n");
for(i=0;i<BFF;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
for ( i = 0; i < BFF; i++ )
    arr[ num[i] - '0' ]++;

printf("\nX | fi\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    if (arr[i])
        printf("%d | %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Me disseram para utilizar a função strtok. Primeiro lendo tudo numa string, depois separa os numeros lidos usando strtok e atoi para converter o numero que está em string para inteiro. Mas n faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.
 Please, help-me.

Comment: Por qual motivo você trata seus números de entrada como string? Onde está o código referente à ordenação?

Comment: Para não ter que informar vários scanf e captura tudo em um só input. Uai, no void sort(); e nos dois for do main?

Answer (score 0):

1- Como o vetor não tem tamanho determinado deve se usar a função malloc() ou calloc().

2- Você pode fazer a leitura e ordenação do vetor. Mas também pode fazer a leitura e depois ordenar o vetor. Alguns algoritmos são: Bubble Sort e Selection Sort. Aqui tem exemplo: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html.

3- A sua leitura deve ser de números inteiro (pelo que eu etendi). Mas você esta usando string.

4- Agora sim você faz a contagem dos números.